# How to configure multiple hostfiles to split big backups in BackupPC?

Tags: backup, incremental-backup, backuppc

With my current configuration the BackupPC creates one rsync(of tar for local) process per host.
My config file is following:
/etc/BackupPC/pc/myhost.pl:

```
$Conf{RsyncShareName} = '/data';
```

In my `/data` I have many folders `/data/01 /data/02 /data/03`. I would like to backup them in parallel.
Is it possible to configure BackupPC in the way that single host backup done in parallel on directory basis?

Answer (score 2):

Found finally! Looking in documentation: host aliases
in /etc/BackupPC/hosts adding lines-

```
localhost.data.01 0 root
localhost.data.02 0 root
localhost.data.03 0 root
```

/etc/BackupPC/pc/localhost.data.o1.pl

```
$Conf{XferMethod} = "tar";
$Conf{TarShareName} = '/data/01';
$Conf{ClientNameAlias} = 'localhost';
```

same for 02,03 folders.

Then backups will start in parallel if `$Conf{MaxBackupPCNightlyJobs}` >1;